# How to populate a Tablix referencing data from another Tablix dataset?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have two `Tablix`: **Tablix A** and **Tablix B**:

Each `Tablix` is connected to different `datasets` as illustrated in the image below:

How do I populate Tablix B by looking up data in Tablix A?

For example: Tablix A contains Vehicle models but I also need to populate Tablix B with Vehicle colors using the VehicleID in both dataset.

Using a `Lookup Function`, this only works if both datasets are references in the same tablix, how do I do this using separate tablix?

Attempting to use separate tablix, I get the below error:

```
[rsFieldReference] The Value expression for the text box 
‘Textbox57’ refers to the field ‘VehicleColor’.  

Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, 
if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. 
Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.
```

Illustration:

[image]

Comment: what is your expression.

Comment: I am using the expressions as explained here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx

`=LookupSet(Fields!TerritoryGroupID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!StoreName.Value, "Stores")`

Comment: have you tried using just "Lookup"

Answer (score 0):

You can use "lookup" to get a single value from another dataset. For example:

```
=Lookup(Fields!VehicleID.Value, Fields!VehicleID.Value, Fields!VehicleColour.Value, "Vehicles")
```

would bring out a single (the first in the dataset) VehicleColour where the IDs matched. If there is only a single match of ID between the two datasets, then the correct colour would be returned.

```
=LookupSet(Fields!VehicleID.Value, Fields!VehicleID.Value, Fields!VehicleColour.Value, "Vehicles")
```

brings out an array, which can only be displayed in a textbox if it's converted into a string using join:

```
=join(LookupSet(Fields!VehicleID.Value, Fields!VehicleID.Value, Fields!VehicleColour.Value, "Vehicles"), ", ")
```

which will bring out a comma separated list of all VehicleColours where the IDs match.

For more information on Lookup, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee210531.aspx

For more information on Lookupset, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx